# After jquery auto refresh a div popup doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, partial-page-refresh

I have a jquery which refreshes the div but after refresh the popup doesn't work from the refreshed data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
        });
        //Refresh trigger `#newORDERx`
        var auto_refreshes = setInterval(function () {$('#newORDERx').load('inc/restAdmin_orders_rcvz.php');}, 1000);
    });
</script>
<div id="newORDERx"></div>
```

When i use it like below then popup works fine but then it doesn't refresh the div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false
            mainClass: 'pp-product-detail' // when i use this then popup works but then doesn't refresh the div
        });
        var auto_refreshes = setInterval(function () {$('#newORDERx').load('inc/restAdmin_orders_rcvz.php');}, 1000);
    });

</script>
```

**pp-product-detail class**

```
AJAX popup

if ($('.pp-product-detail').length) {
   $('.pp-product-detail').magnificPopup({
       type: 'ajax'
   });
}
```

**restAdmin_orders_rcvz.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="the-menu-item">
    <div class="image-wrap">
      <a class="pp-product-detail" href="product-detail-popup-rest-admin-order-rcv.php?iid=<?php echo $phporder; ?>">
      <img src="images/themenu/img-1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="the-menu-body">
      <b><font color='red'> Order # </font> <?php echo $phporder; ?><br>
      <font color='red'> Items Included : </font> <?php echo $lrsa['count']; ?>
      <br><font color='red'>Dated : </font> <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($phpdates)); ?>
      </b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see where is the popup trigger... But I suppose it is in the `#newORDERx`... Since this element gets "refreshed", or re-written, the element which triggers the popup is too. You just have to modify the event handler (which you didn't provided) : `$("#popupTrigger").on("click",function(){...}` to `$(document).on("click","#popupTrigger",function(){...}`

Comment: What "popup"?  What is "popping up" and what causes it to "pop up" in the first place?

Comment: What is `pp-product-detail` class ?

Comment: Then show it! ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette check the update

Comment: any further help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added following file in `restAdmin_orders_rcvz.php` and its working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

**restAdmin_orders_rcvz.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="the-menu-item">
    <div class="image-wrap">
      <a class="pp-product-detail" href="product-detail-popup-rest-admin-order-rcv.php?iid=<?php echo $phporder; ?>">
      <img src="images/themenu/img-1.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="the-menu-body">
      <b><font color='red'> Order # </font> <?php echo $phporder; ?><br>
      <font color='red'> Items Included : </font> <?php echo $lrsa['count']; ?>
      <br><font color='red'>Dated : </font> <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($phpdates)); ?>
      </b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... I'm pretty sure that the problem is in your `class`, since you re-write the `.pp-product-detail` element...

So try to change it to this:

```
if ($(document).find('.pp-product-detail').length) {
   $(document).find('.pp-product-detail').magnificPopup({
       type: 'ajax'
   });
}
```

Comment: still one time it open the popup and several times it will open the file in url

Comment: mmm... Do you have a live link to share ?

Comment: Ha! And are you sure to be able to perform ajax requests in your local environnement? Try it live... This can be the issue.

Comment: its working fine if i dont refresh it only it is causing when i refresh the div